# 404 error is coming in WordPress after clicking on Update due to inline style in WYSIWYG

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg, wp-editor

When I'm setting the text formatting through the WYSIWYG **WP editor** and then clicking on Update, I'm getting 404 Error page.

[Click Here to View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNpe4.png)

And If I removed the Text Formatting, Then Page updating works is Fine.

This issue also come in the Message body of the **Contact Form 7** , when I'm adding custom HTML template in message body:

[Click Here to View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PltVX.png)